# using mouse control in a game in C

Tags: c, dos

I'm new to programming the mouse in C, so can someone please expalin me this basic code?

```
#include <dos.h>  
union REGS in, out;

void detect_mouse ()
{
    in.x.ax = 0;
    int86 (0X33,&in,&out);   //invoke interrupt
    if (out.x.ax == 0)
        printf ("\nMouse Failed To Initialize");
    else
        printf ("\nMouse was Succesfully Initialized");
}

int main ()
{
    detect_mouse ();
    getch ();
}
```

Comment: What is cso? What exactly you do not understand?

Comment: void detect_mouse function.plz help me with that

Comment: "mouse in cso can" = "mouse in C so can" :)

Comment: @cup Wow! How did you decipher that? O_o

Comment: sorry it is my mistake but can you please help me understanding this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be code for old, plain MS DOS which would query if the mouse driver (mouse.com/mouse.sys) is loaded or not.

To talk to mouse.sys, you had to fill some processor registers with specific contents, execute interrupt 0x33, then check the processor registers for return values. That's what the function does. You can find a list of most possible register contents and functions here: http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/rbinter/ix/33/00.html

Comment: @user3066373: Welcome to SO! Your status suggests you have not yet read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page; please do so at your convenience. If you like an answer, please formally Accept it. Posting a "Thanks" is not required.